# Why doesnt keyframes animation work in safari

Tags: css

So I´m working on a gallery for my page, and wanted some animation. What I want is for the images to go from border-radius 50% to 0%. This works just fine in chrome, but I cant get It to work on safari. Here is the CSS:

```
.bild {
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 95%;
  width: 95%;
  -webkit-animation-name: out;
  -webkit-animation-duration: .9s;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.bild:hover{
  -webkit-animation-name: in;
  -webkit-animation-duration: .9s;
  border-radius: 0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes in {
  0% {border-radius: 50%;}
  100% {border-radius: 0%;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes out {
  0% {border-radius: 0%;}
  100% {border-radius: 50%;}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score -2):

You should try with CSS mixins. Different browsers require different prefixes for some styles:

```
-webkit-animation-duration: $duration;
-moz-animation-duration:    $duration;
-ms-animation-duration:     $duration;
-o-animation-duration:      $duration;
animation-duration:         $duration;

-webkit-animation-name: $animation-name;
-moz-animation-name:    $animation-name;
-ms-animation-name:     $animation-name;
-o-animation-name:      $animation-name;
animation-name:         $animation-name;

@-webkit-keyframes in {
    0% {border-radius: 50%;}
  100% {border-radius: 0%;}
}

@-moz-keyframes in {
    0% {border-radius: 50%;}
  100% {border-radius: 0%;}
}

@-ms-keyframes in {
    0% {border-radius: 50%;}
  100% {border-radius: 0%;}
}

@-o-keyframes in {
    0% {border-radius: 50%;}
  100% {border-radius: 0%;}
}

@keyframes in {
    0% {border-radius: 50%;}
  100% {border-radius: 0%;}
}
```

Note that you need also keyframes for 'out' animation-name in your case.

If this doesn't help, please provide HTML code or create a Codepen so we can see the whole code isolated.

Comment: prefixes are not more needed for animation since too long